# W3C validator: Bad value for attribute href on element a: Missing scheme

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have the piece of code from below, but I get the error which says "Bad value for attribute href on element a: Missing scheme." when I validate the code.
How can I fix this?

```
<a class="contact_mobile_link" href="tel:0511-87989280">0511-87989280</a>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a space at the beginning of the `href` attribute. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

the validator expects to see a valid schema in the `href=""` property.

Your screenshot clearly shows that the first character in there is a   (space)

Remove that, and try with `href="tel:051187989280"`